# Push Notification on Web view app using Xamarin and Firebase

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I send push notification to a web view application using Xamarin and Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Here is a [Xamarin Firebase Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/) but there are also others. This question is too broad though. Try to implement it and come back with a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: I have a web view application made using Xamarin.Forms that views a food ordering website. The user will register/login to order food. The user's login details are sent to the external database and stored. How can I store the user's Firebase Cloud Messaging (fcm) token together with the user's login details?

Comment: You can get token every time you restart the app and upload it when user login.

Comment: How can I upload it when the user logs in since it is a web view app?

Comment: You can have a try with [Invoke C# from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#invoke-c-from-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

To add push notification ability to your app ,you have to implement it in each platform project:

For Android, please read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows), there are detailed steps about how to implement `remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

For iOS, You can use [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/) to send iOS push notification by FCM.

There are also steps here: [Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#about-firebase-cloud-messaging)